# Select features that do not intersect with another polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, select

See the image below. What I want to do is select all features that do NOT intersect with the features of the selected layer. How do I go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: have you tried ticking the "check" disjoint?

Comment: Welp that did it, sucked that the documentation didn't explain this. Thanks

Comment: Seems pretty clear in the documentation -https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location

Answer (score 2):

Just invert the selection after Select by Location:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments, use **Disjoint**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who came across this several times and want the segment of lines outside of the polygon, Difference is the answer.
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9h9n.jpg)

[Image of QGIS Difference Map
1.Pink Lines
2.Grey dissolved polygons
3."Difference" process
4.Orange resulting segments]